# None capturing groups in regex not working as expected

Tags: python, regex, capturing-group

The following match patter does look for the character `/` not having a blank space before it, but having a blank or a dot or a line ending after it.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"[^ ]/([ .]|$)", "Foo /markup/ bar")                                                                                                                                   
<re.Match object; span=(10, 13), match='p/ '>
```

I'm not interested only in the `/` and its position. Here I do use a simplified regex as an MWE. In the original I'm not able to just do `pos = m.start() + 1` to get the position of `/`.

I assume *no capturing groups* (`(?:)`) are but I can't get them work. The result I expect would be

```
<re.Match object; span=(11, 11), match='/'>
```

What do I make wrong here?

```
>>> re.search(r"(?:[^ ])/(?:[ .]|$)", "Foo /markup/ bar")                                                                                                                             
<re.Match object; span=(10, 13), match='p/ '>
```

Comment: Note that the term "blank space" in regex world mostly refers to a regular space and a TAB char. "Whitespace" refers to any kind of line breaks, carriage returns, tabs, line separators, hard/soft spaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
m = re.search(r"(?<!\s)/(?![^\s.])", "Foo /markup/ bar")
if m:
    print(m.start()) # => 11
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/eUOXHh).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\s)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with whitespace
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?![^\s.])` - a negative lookahead that requires a whitespace, `.` char or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

**NOTE**: If you do not expect matches to be at the start of the string, replace `(?<!\s)` with `(?<=\S)` that will require any non-whitespace char to appear immediately to the left of the `/` char.

Comment: I don't get the difference between `(?<!` and `(?<=`. And why not using `[^ ]` meaning "not a whitespace" instead of playing around with `/s`?

Comment: @buhtz `\s` matches any whitespace chars, if you only need to account for literal space char, use a space. `(?<!\s)` also matches at the start of string while `(?<=\S)` never matches at the start of the string. `[^ ]` matches and *consumes* a char other than a regular space.

Comment: I see. Playing around with some variants I would prefer `(?<!\s)/(?=[\s.])` mixing positive and negative looks because it is more natural to human thinking. "Match a `/` not having a white space  in front but having a whitespace or dot after it."

Comment: @buhtz  Ok, but note that `(?=[\s.])` *requires* a whitespace or dot char immediately to the right of the current position, and thus will never match a `/` at the end of string. `(?![^\s.])` (equal to `(?=[\s.]|$)`) will also allow matches at the end of a string.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I would describe `(?![^\s.])` as an inverted negation. That is not how human brains work. ;) Regex is complicated enough by its own. No need to make it harder than it is. Machines should adapt to us not we to the machines.

Comment: @buhtz That is double negation, and is more efficient than the counterpart with alternation since alternation always means more backtracking (-> more overhead). "Machines should adapt to us not we to the machines." - .NET regex follows this path (cf. [.NET 7.0+ regex improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/regular-expression-improvements-in-dotnet-7/)), not Python `re`.